# Radon measure, Riesz's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set and 
$$
T:C_{c}\left(\Omega\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
 be a positive linear functional, where $C_{c}\left(\Omega\right):=\left\{ f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:f\textrm{ is continous, compactly support}\right\} .$
By Riesz's theorem, there is a (unique) positive Radon measure $\mu$
such that 
$$
\left\langle T,f\right\rangle =\intop_{\Omega}fd\mu;\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\right).
$$
My question is: is it always true that $\mu\left(\Omega\right)<+\infty$?

In Exercise 16, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/, the author claimed that it's true. Am i wrong?

Thank.

Comment: there is an additional hypothesis in exercise 16, that the functional be _continuous_.

Comment: any positive linear functional is automatically continuous

Comment: ??, what is "bounded"?

Comment: why do u confirm "no"?

Comment: The norm of a linear functional $T$ is $$\lVert T\rVert = \sup\{\lvert Tx\rvert~:~\lVert x\rVert\leq 1\}.$$ A linear functional is bounded if its norm is finite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59551/discussion-between-binjiu-and-user363464).

Comment: Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Tf = \int_{\Omega} f(x)\,dx$. But in exercise 16, Tao asks about _continuous_ (with respect to the $L^{\infty}$-norm) linear functionals, and that implies that $\mu$ has finite variation.

Comment: Dear Fischer, do you mean that in Tao's exercise: ``$T\in\left(C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right)\right)^{\star}$
is continuous'' means if $\left\Vert f_{k}-f\right\Vert _{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)}\rightarrow0$
then $T\left(f_{k}\right)\rightarrow T\left(f\right)?$

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $\Omega = {\mathbb R}^n$ or any open unbounded set with infinite Lebesgue measure,  and let $T f = \int f(x) dx$.

Even if $\Omega$ is bounded, the answer is still negative. Here's a simple example. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\Omega$ converging to a point in $\partial \Omega$, and let

$T f =\sum_n f(a_n) $.

If $f$ is compactly supported, then the sum is finite. If, in addition, $f$ is nonnegative, then the sum is nonnegative.

Also, by definition, $Tf$ is the integral of $f$ with respect to an infinite measure $\sum_n \delta_{a_n}$.

Finally, for Tao's notes. I did not read thoroughly, but I seriously doubt that there is such a claim. If you're referring to Theorem 8, then note that a Radon measure is not necessarily finite (one of the first examples is Lebesgue measure). If you're referring to Exercise 16, note that the assumption $I \in C_c(\Omega)^*$ is somewhat stronger, and excludes the two examples above, the reason being $C_c(\Omega)^*=C_0(\Omega)^*$ ($C_0(\Omega)$ is the  space of continuous functions ``vanishing at $\infty$", equipped with the $\sup$-norm. This  is a Banach space), and the functionals defined in the two examples above are not bounded on $C_0(\Omega)$. Recall that  $C_c({\Omega})$ is NOT a Banach space: its closure is $C_0({\mathbb \Omega})$. Perhaps this is the source of confusion.

Comment: In my understanding, $T:C_{c}\left(\Omega\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is called ``continuous'' if for any compact subset $K,$ there is
$C_{K}>0$ such that $\left|\left\langle T,f\right\rangle \right|\leq C_{k}\left|f\right|_{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)};$
$\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\right)$ and $supp\left(f\right)\subset K.$
Thank for your answer. It's now clear that $\mu\left(\Omega\right)$
is not necessarily finite in the sense that $T$ is continuous as
this kind.

Comment: However, Tao means $T$ is continuous in a different sense,
that is $\left|\left\langle T,f\right\rangle \right|\leq C_{k}\left|f\right|_{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)};$
$\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\right).$ Am i right?

Comment: @Binjiu Yes. To put it in a different way, a measure is finite if and only if the constant $C_K$ can be chosen the same for ALL compact sets.

Comment: @Binjiu Topologically the difference is that the space of finite measures is the dual of $(C_c(\mathbb R), \| . \|_\infty)$. Now this space is dense in $(C_0(\mathbb R), \| . \|_\infty)$, and hence they have the same dual. The space of Radon measures is the dual of $C_c(\mathbb R)$ with respect to the so called inductive topology: For each compact set $K$ the space $$C_c(\mathbb R:K):= \{ f \in C_c(\mathbb R:K) | \supp(f) \subset K \}$$ is a Banach subspace of $(C_0(\mathbb R), \| . \|_\infty)$, and now we can take the inductive limit by compact $K$.

Comment: @Binju Now, it is easy to see that with respect to the inductive topology, a functional is continuous if and only if for any compact subset $K$, there exists a $C_K>0$ such that $$\left| \langle T,f \rangle \right| \leq C_{K} \| f \|_{\infty}; \forall f \in C_c\left(\mathbb R \right); supp(f) \subset K$$. So 'continuous' really means continuous with respect to the right (i.e. inductive topology). Last but not least, there are various versions of Riesz Theorem, which apply to these different situations (also positive vs signed vs complex). The equivalence between them....

Comment: Can u explain more? What did Tao mean: $T\in C_{c}\left(X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right)^{\star}$
continuous? What is $C_{c};C_{0}?$ I explained the mean of continuity in my understanding as above.

Comment: ... is a fast consequence of the fact that the restriction of a measure to a compact set is a finite measure. Here $C_c$ means compactly supported continuous functions while $C_0$ means functions vanishing at infinity (in $\mathbb R$ this simply means has a $0$ limit at $\pm \infty$, but can be defined on any locally compact space) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59553/discussion-between-binjiu-and-n-s).